# What happens when Graphics.MeasureString() is called?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to measure the pixel width of a string, using the MeasureString() method of a graphics object.

I am creating a new graphics object using CreateGraphics(), and using it to call MeasureString(). Once, I am done, I call dispose() on it.

My question is that whether calling MeasureString() actually causes rendering to occur. I am not using any drawing method, though (such as DrawString, etc).

-Dev

Comment: No.  It just measures the string - it does not render it.

Comment: Please show some code. It doesn't actually.

Comment: Did you try a ten seconds search *MeasureString* in google?

Comment: You are doing two things wrong.  Worrying about something you cannot change.  And using the wrong method, MeasureString is only appropriate on a printer.  Use the TextRenderer class for text output on a monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public SizeF MeasureString(String text, Font font, SizeF layoutArea, StringFormat stringFormat) 
{
    if (text == null || text.Length == 0)
    {
        return new SizeF(0, 0);
    }

    if (font == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("font");
    }

    GPRECTF grfLayout = new GPRECTF(0, 0, layoutArea.Width, layoutArea.Height);
    GPRECTF grfboundingBox = new GPRECTF();

    int a, b;
    int status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipMeasureString(new HandleRef(this, this.NativeGraphics), text, text.Length, new HandleRef(font, font.NativeFont), 
            ref grfLayout, 
            new HandleRef(stringFormat, (stringFormat == null) ? IntPtr.Zero : stringFormat.nativeFormat), 
            ref grfboundingBox, out a, out b);

    if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok)
    {
        throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);
    }

    return grfboundingBox.SizeF;
}
```

So no, no rendering occurs. Even the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6xe5hazb(v=vs.110).aspx) says so:

> Measures the specified string when drawn with the specified Font.

Answer (score 1):

As the method name suggests, it doesn't.